# Why does this type conversion [not] work?

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider the following code ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Um4-pZ)):

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    void method();
};

template <typename T> struct Member;
template <typename T> struct Member<void (T::*)()>
{
    using Object = T;
};

template <typename T> class Pointer
{
public:
    operator T*();
};

template <typename Func>
void bar(typename Member<Func>::Object*, Func) {}

void test()
{
    Pointer<Foo> p;
    bar(p, &Foo::method);
}
```

This compiles with GCC ≥ 4.9, but GCC 4.8 doesn't know to invoke the conversion operator:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'bar(Pointer<Foo>&, void (Foo::*)())'
     bar(p, &Foo::method);
note: candidate is:
note: template<class Func> void bar(typename Member<Func>::Object*, Func) void bar(typename Member<Func>::Object*, Func) {}
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   mismatched types 'typename Member<Func>::Object*' and 'Pointer<Foo>'
     bar(p, &Foo::method);
```

Why? Is it a bug? Is it a new feature in C++14? Please cite either the C++ feature or GCC bug report if possible.

Thanks!

(Note: I have a work-around for my real code, I'm just wondering what changed in the compiler...)

Comment: If it compiles with `-std=c++11` in more recent versions of GCC, then it is about the compiler, not C++14 vs C++11.

Comment: @Ayxan, hmm, good point, so probably I am looking for a compiler bug...

Comment: That said, it's technically possible this was flagged as a language defect and fixed retroactively... but more likely it's a bug, GCC 4.8.x is known for having a number.

Comment: If you have some CPU to burn, you can `git bisect` gcc...

Comment: @NateEldredge, no thanks ☺.